# C++ application exit error code 62097 - What does that mean?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, error-code

My program is exitting with code '62097' (or in hex 0xF291).
I know which DLL library is causing it, and I'm trying to figure out why it is messing up.

What does 62097 mean? How can I find out? I checked online, and [as far](http://www.hiteksoftware.com/knowledge/articles/049.htm) as I [can tell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381.aspx), generic Windows error codes don't go up to 62097.

Any other suggestions how I can go about debugging this problem?
I use Dependency Walker on the DLL that's causing trouble, but everything is fine except missing IESHIMS.dll, IEFRAME.dll, and SHLWAPI.dll (which usually are missing when I use Dependency Walker).

The library in question is a 3rd party library that I compiled myself - it's quite possible I compiled it incorrectly - how can I tell if that's the case?

The program refuses to run before it enters main(), but only if I use a class imported from the DLL. If I'm not using anything from the DLL, the program starts fine.

The program is technically "running", but in the background, before the code ever reaches me. It's not a constructor of a class, because I tried doing something like this:

```
dllClass *class = new dllClass;
```

And the same thing occurred before execution reached the 'new', so it can't be a constructor with an infinite loop or something like that.
It's running as a process, and is *not* "Not responding".

I'm using MinGW on Windows 7 32bit. What can I do to troubleshoot this?
I appreciate any insight you can offer; meanwhile I'm trying to follow up a few more possible thoughts hoping I can narrow it down further.

Comment: Does the suspected dll have a `DllMain`? Are all binaries 32-bit? Asides from that, it seems like some static initialization, which is performed when the dll is loaded, is failing.

Comment: Can you try statically linking to the library, instead of making it into a DLL?

Comment: I compiled the library as a part of the project that used it, and it runs. However, it seems that if I exit my program too soon after launching, it sometimes throws an exception.

Since it's now a part of my project itself, I can walk through it with a debugger and breakpoints, and track down the problem. I don't know why I didn't think to do that sooner! Thanks for the tips, gentlemen! =)
I bet the errorcode has something to do with throwing exceptions across DLL boundries.

Comment: I'm getting this when an attempt to allocate memory fails.

Answer (score 3):

This library is made using Qt ? Because according to http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2013-March/010157.html it the return code Qt uses when it kills a process.

Comment: Alas, it was a year ago, so I don't remember the exact incident. Since I use Qt, it was likely a Qt library, or else another library (SFML) interacting with Qt.

You'd have thought that they'd've used a constant with a descriptive name and a comment. =) Then again, you'd have thought I would've posted what DLL was causing me a problem.

Comment: Do you have any more details about when and why this magic number gets triggered? I see in the link you posted that it's related to killing a process, but is there any more details that may be useful to others having the problem in the future? Anything that indicates *why* Qt killed the process, letting the developer know what the problem is?