# Killing ffmpeg from Qt results in a corrupt video file

Tags: qt, windows-7, ffmpeg

I'm using Qt to record stream data from a Mobotix camera on Windows 7. The command I use is:

`ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i "http://admin:password@192.168.0.100/control/faststream.jpg?stream=full" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -c:a copy out.mp4`

This works fine from the command line and when I want to stop it I just do Ctrl-C. But I'm  doing this from an application using Qt 5.2 via a QProcess. After 10 minutes I want to stop the recording so I tried [QProcess::terminate()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#terminate) but this doesn't stop it. [QProcess::kill()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#kill) works but the resulting video won't play. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567273/killing-infinite-ffmpeg-on-the-command-line-from-an-application) suggests I'm doing it the right way.

I connect to [QProcess::finished()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#finished) so when I call QProcess::kill() the result is:

- int exitCode = 62097
- [QProcess::ExitStatus](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#ExitStatus-enum) exitStatus = QProcess::CrashExit

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187021/c-application-exit-error-code-62097-what-does-that-mean) this is the return code Qt uses when it kills a process.

So is there any other way for me to either terminate the process gracefully (the same as pressing Ctrl-C) or perform this same functionality via an ffmpeg library so I can stop it properly?

Comment: why are you using `H.264` video in `AVI` container? Can you try outputing to a `.mp4` or `.mkv` file?

Comment: Sorry, cut and paste error.

Answer (score 3):

I explain the correct way for handling the same exact issue in that thread:
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/47654/

its very simple all you need is to send q for quit signal this is simple example:

```
myProcess->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);
myProcess->write("q");
myProcess->closeWriteChannel();
```

keep in mind you also have to exit your parent process too... good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Qt doesn't have a portable way to do this. However, you can use [`QProcess::processId()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#processId) to get a native process PID which you can use. On `POSIX-complitable` systems you can use [`kill(pid, SIGINT)`](http://man.he.net/?topic=kill&section=2) to send a `Ctrl-C`. Just include `signal.h` and `sys/types.h`. On Windows it's harder, look on this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows)

Comment: Unfortunately QProcess::processId() says "This function was introduced in Qt 5.3" and I'm currently using Qt 5.2. I have to use QProcess::pid() instead.